# R - match strings between two columns

Tags: r, string, grepl

I have two columns, one identifier (C1) and one target (C2).

```
C1  C2
qw  qw, er
er  ty
ty  ty
```

Now, I need to search for elements of C1 in corresponding strings of C2. In this example the result would be:

```
C3
ALSO
NONE
ONLY
```

I used `grepl(C1, C2)` inside a `case_when` statement, but then only the first element of C1 is used for matching:

```
C3 <- case_when(C1==C2~"ONLY",
                grepl(C1, C2)~"ALSO",
                TRUE~"NONE")
```

ONLY results are okay as they do not need string matching, and NONE results are the leftovers after ONLY and ALSO. Please suggest the easiest way to do this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I tried doing this with `mapply` and `stri_detect_fixed` from `stringi`

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringi)

df$C3 <- case_when(stri_detect_fixed(df$C1, df$C2) ~ "ONLY", 
                   mapply(function(x, y) grepl(x, y), df$C1, df$C2) ~ "ALSO", 
                   TRUE~"NONE")

df$C3
#[1] "ALSO" "NONE" "ONLY"
```

Although, there should be some better way to to use `grepl` instead of `mapply`.

Comment: Thankfully my dataset is fairly small, otherwise this code is way too cumbersome. Thank you for the solution anyway.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be the most graceful solution, but you can use `apply` in row mode to do the `grepl` calculation.  Then use `case_when` with this result:

```
df$result <- case_when(df$C1 == df$C2 ~ "ONLY",
                       apply(df, 1, function(x) grepl(x[1], x[2])) ~ "ALSO",
                       TRUE ~ "NONE")
```

Comment: I need to check which one is faster, will update here once done.

Comment: Both apply and mapply functions have almost same execution time but the mapply function is more position agnostic.

Answer (score 1):

`rowwise` can be useful in this case to do calculation on each row seperately. 
Suppose `df` is the original data frame with columns `C1` and `C2` below should work

```
library(dplyr)
df <- df %>% rowwise %>% 
mutate(C3 = case_when(C1==C2~"ONLY", grepl(C1, C2)~"ALSO", TRUE~"NONE")) %>%
 ungroup
```